# Prevent Vuetify v-tabs from change

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

Is there a way to prevent the v-tabs from actually changing when being clicked on?

In my case I first need to check if stuff on the page has changed and want to cancel the switch to another tab if it has.

Neither a event.prevent nor event.stop will stop the v-tabs from changing:
`<v-tab @click.prevent.stop="..."> ... </v-tab>`

At the moment I'm using a `window.requestAnimationFrame` to reset the tab index to the old value. It gets the job done but this feels like a really nasty technique to me.

HTML:

```
    <v-tabs v-model="currentIndex">
        <v-tab v-for="(route, index) in list" :key="index" @change="handleTabChange(route, $event)" >
            {{ route.meta.title }}
        </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
```

TS:

```
public handleTabChange(routeConf:RouteConfig):void {
    let currentIndex:number = this.currentIndex;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.currentIndex = currentIndex;
            Store.app.router.goto(routeConf.name, null, this.$route.params);
            // Once the page actually changes this.currentIndex is set to the correct index..
        });
}
```

Comment: Instead of using click.prevent.stop use click.stop.prevent

Comment: @chans that still doesn't stop the v-tabs from changing

Answer (score 12):

I solve this problem by using separate variable between `v-tabs` and `v-tabs-items`.

```html
<v-tabs v-model="tab" @change="onTabChange">
  <v-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item">
    {{ item }}
  </v-tab>
</v-tabs>

<v-tabs-items v-model="currentTab">
  <v-tab-item v-for="item in items" :key="item">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>{{ item }}</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

```js
methods: {
  onTabChange() {
    if (/* reject */) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.tab = this.currentTab
      })
    } else {
      this.currentTab = this.tab
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/68wygn2k/)

Another possible solution is to extend the `v-tab` component which is a bit more complicated but can actually override the behavior.

Create new file `my-tab.js`:

```js
import { VTab } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
  extends: VTab,

  methods: {
    async click (e) {
      if (this.disabled) {
        e.preventDefault()
        return
      }

      // <-- your conditions
      let ok = await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(false)
        }, 2000)
      })

      if (!ok) {
        this.$el.blur()
        return
      }
      // -->

      if (this.href &&
        this.href.indexOf('#') > -1
      ) e.preventDefault()

      if (e.detail) this.$el.blur()

      this.$emit('click', e)

      this.to || this.toggle()
    }
  }
}
```

> The original source code is [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/999a84466911757c5876769272bc61b6e3cbd1c0/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTabs/VTab.ts#L79-L100). You can also override the `render` function to change the styles.

Then just use it as normal component:

```html
<v-tabs v-model="tab">
  <my-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item">
    {{ item }}
  </my-tab>
</v-tabs>

<v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
  <v-tab-item v-for="item in items" :key="item">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text
        >{{ item }} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
        enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-card-text
      >
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

Comment: Worth pointing out, this does not work for async reject() method (e.g. async confirmation dialog), visually it still changes the tab and then changes it back.

Comment: @wondra Thank you for pointing out. I update my answer.  And this is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-perlman-c4eup). Unfortunately I can't run it due to poor performance. I copied from my local. I hope it will work.

Comment: Your demo is hanging up after switching tabs. I think your answer is no more an applicable solution.

Comment: @ShadowGames Could you please explain more? I'm not sure which demo you're referring to. I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/68wygn2k/ and it still works as expected, when you are in the second tab, you will no longer be able to go to another tab.

Comment: @User28 I have misunderstood the OP's requirement. Your demo is working as intended - apologies / my bad!

Answer (score 3):

For me it works the following way:

```
...
<v-tab href="#tab-1">Tab-1</v-tab>
<v-tab href="#tab-2" @click.native.prevent.stop.capture="goto2()">Tab-2</v-tab>
...

...
private goto2() {
  if(tab-1Changes) {
    // do something
    return;
  }
  this.tab = "tab-2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to follow this way in your code this is example which will help you:

In ts file:

```
<template>
  <v-tabs v-model="activeTab">
     <v-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id" :to="tab.route">{{ tab.name }} 
     </v-tab>

     <v-tabs-items v-model="activeTab" @change="updateRouter($event)">
        <v-tab-item v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id" :to="tab.route">
            <router-view />          
        </v-tab-item>
     </v-tabs-items>
   </v-tabs>
</template>
```

Script:

```
export default {
data: () => ({
    activeTab: '',
    tabs: [
        {id: '1', name: 'Tab A', route: 'component-a'},
        {id: '2', name: 'Tab B', route: 'component-b'}
    ]
}),
methods: {
    updateRouter(val){
        this.$router.push(val)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see how this stops the tabs from changing. Also I don't use v-tabs-items; just the tab bar itself.